# Android host device detection

Tags: android, usb, pic

I want to make an app that controls the LEDs connected  to PIC18F4550.I am going to send an array for that but before sending any data I want to detect my usb device.For detection I found simple example but It is not working and couldn't find where I am doing it wrong.

Can anyone help me with that ?

Best regards.

Here is my mainActivity:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

    while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){

        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Value of device :" +device.getDeviceName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

        }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.usbsenderandroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="12" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.usbsenderandroid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                   android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

device_filter:

```
 <resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1240" product-id="0063" />
 </resources>
```

And this is details when i connect my pic

HID\VID_04D8&PID_003F&REV_0002

HID\VID_04D8&PID_003F

HID_DEVICE_UP:FF00_U:0001

HID_DEVICE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am feeling kind of sad to answering my own question but I figured it out guys. The problem is not about the code. I found in pic's form page : **"An Android accessory must be a USB host. The 18F USB PICs are devices, not hosts"**. Here is the link for the  [description](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m626926-print.aspx)

Comment: That's true, but not really relevant, as the code you have above not for an "Android accessory" but rather for the case where the Android device is the USB host, and the external device is the USB slave.  So your project is potentially workable, *provided that your particular Android device supports the optional USB host mode*

Comment: I get confused, So are you telling me that, It is possible to communicate with pic18f4550 with my android phone ? if yes could you explain to me how ?

Comment: If your particular phone has the **optional** USB host mode and you use an OTG cable adapter with the select pin grounded, and that PIC has a USB device interface, then yes.

Comment: I can get that OTG cable not a big deal.Before real device i want to try on Simulator. Is it possible to do that with simulator ?

Comment: I would be surprised, but see what the documentation says.